# Handling large number of http requests with Apache as Webserver, PHP at application layer and MongoDB

Tags: php, node.js, mongodb, jmeter, load-testing

I have an API written in PHP with two very basic functionality as getUserData and UpdateUserData that interacts with MongoDB using **MongoDB Driver 1.4.2 for PHP**.
We expect about **1500 requests per second** (1000 for getUserData and about 500 for updateUserData).
I have configured apache to handle maximum clients upto 1500 at the same time, making changes in the MPM configurations.
When I test this setup using Jmeter, results are not very impressive considering the capability of MongoDB.

[image: Jmeter Response Time Graph]

I think, MongoDB Driver is **not making persistent connections** as I can see more than 1300 connections open, after the test.How can I avoid this **handshaking** ? Can using **nodejs** instead of **PHP** be helpfull for me ?

Comment: you really need to provide your php code, sql and db structure for us to help you out.  A graph and explanation is nice but doesn't give us any insight into where your bottleneck could be

Comment: You should also be monitoring [at a minimum] CPU, RAM, and IO load on all involved servers, if not of each service individually.

Comment: I think RAM is the bottleneck, I am using a windows server with 4GB of RAM, and the mongo DB has around 20 million records. Is 4GB enough to handle such load ? How do I get memory used by a single Apache process ?